# Nested pipeline in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-spark, stream, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Apache Beam pipeline takes an infinite stream of messages. Each message fans out N elements (N is ~1000 and is different for each input). Then for each element produced by the previous stage there is a *map* operation that produces new N elements, which should be reduced using a *top 1* operation (elements are grouped by the original message that was read from the queue). The results of *top 1* is saved to an external storage. In Spark I can easily do it by reading messages from the stream and creating RDD for each message that does map + reduce. Since Apache Beam does not have nested pipelines, I can't see a way implementing it in Beam with an infinite stream input. Example:

```
Infinite stream elements: A, B

Step 1 (fan out, N = 3): A -> A1, A2, A3
                (N = 2): B -> B1, B2

Step 2 (map): A1, A2, A3 -> A1', A2', A3'
              B1, B2, B3 -> B1', B2'

Step 3 (top1): A1', A2', A3' -> A2'
               B1', B2' -> B3'

Output: A2', B2'
```

There is no dependency between A and B elements. A2' and B2' are top elements withing their group. The stream is infinite. The map operation can take from a couple of seconds to a couple of minutes. Creating a window watermark for the maximum time it takes to do the map operation would make the overall pipeline time much slower for fast map operations. Nested pipeline would help because this way I could create a pipeline per message.

Comment: You can accomplish this in beam, however, you would need to use windowing along with triggers. That being said, in your infinite stream, do you want to keep track of the top across all the data seen in the stream or that particular window (in your case when N = 3 and later when N = 6)? I could write a minimum example if you could explain a bit more on your desired grouping/mapping operations

Comment: @HarisNadeem Clarified the question to say that the top should be calculated per group - one element for A and element for B. The top result should be emitted as soon as it's available. The total time it can take to get from A to A2' can be from 30 seconds to 10 minutes.

Comment: I see, your use case makes more sense now since I was confused what a message was defined as. This is still doable in Apache beam but there are two ways to do it. Since each message is independent from each other, you simply need to do a mapreduce on the message. But since you want to write to storage you would need windowing otherwise you'll never close the file descriptor. So the question would be how to implement it with the least computing time with the least amount of wasting of resources. Correct? If so, I can scale a solution up for you.

Comment: Another way (it's more of a hack) would be to use the storage api and manually write to file in your DoFn and you would then need to manually close the file descriptor at the end of the DoFn function. This way you don't need windowing and would just be running an infinite stream.

Comment: @HarisNadeem Right, it's map reduce on each message, which makes it not a typical data stream. The overhead associated with windowing should be as close to zero as possible, meaning flushing the result every minute from a window would not be acceptable. I'm curious about both windowing and a "hacky" solution though.

Comment: Silly question but would you happen to know the rate that the message is coming in? For example, 10 messages per second. It doesn't have to be accurate, but a ballpark figure would be nice to better think of minimizing windowing overhead. Tbh, I do not know how much overhead a window adds but will look into it.

Comment: @HarisNadeem 10 messages per second is a valid assumption. Overhead caused by the window framework itself is fine, what I am trying to avoid is waiting for a window to close in order to produce a result. If there is a trigger, it should be invoked as soon as the result is available.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you'd need a 'nested pipeline' for this. Let me show you what that looks like in the Beam Python SDK (it's similar for Java):

For example, try the dummy operation of appending a number, and an apostrophe to a string (e.g. `"A"`=>`"A1'"`), you'd do something like this:

```
def my_fn(value):
  def _inner(elm):
    return (elm, elm + str(value) + "'")  # A KV-pair
  return _inner

# my_stream has [A, B]
pcoll_1 = (my_stream
           | beam.Map(my_fn(1)))
pcoll_2 = (my_stream
           | beam.Map(my_fn(2)))
pcoll_3 = (my_stream
           | beam.Map(my_fn(3)))

def top_1(elms):
  ... # Some operation

result = ((pcoll_1, pcoll_2, pcoll_3)
          | beam.CoGroupByKey()
          | beam.Map(top_1))
```

Comment: In my case, N can be 1000 or more and depends on the input message. I edited the answer to reflect this. Also, how will *group by* work in this case? It's an infinite stream, and the map operation can take a couple of minutes. Will dataflow now that all map operations that belong to the original message completed and its now time to do the reduce and save the result to an external storage?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the sort of working solution. I will most likely be editing it for any mistakes I may make in understanding the question. (P.s. the template code is in java). Assuming that `input` is your stream source

```
PCollection<Messages> msgs = input.apply(Window.<Messages>into(        
                                    FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)) 
                                                .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                         // fire the moment you see an element 
                                                   .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))
                                         //optional since you have small window 
                                                   .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                                                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(60))
                                                .discardingFiredPanes());
```

This would allow you to read a stream of `Messages` which could either be a string or a HashMap or even a list. Observe that you are telling beam to fire a window for every element that it receives and you have set a maximum windowing of 1 second. You can change this if you want to fire every 10 messages and a window of a minute etc.

After that you would need to write 2 classes that extend DoFn primarily

```
PCollection<Element> top = msgs.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractElements()))
                               .apply(ParDo.of(new TopElement()));
```

Where `Element` can be a String, an int, double, etc.

Finally, you would right ***each*** `Element` to storage with:

```
top.apply(ParDo.of(new ParsetoString()))
   .apply(TextIO.write().withWindowedWrites()
                        .withNumShards(1)
                        .to(filename));
```

Therefore, you would have roughly 1 file for every message which may be a lot. But sadly you can not append to file. Unless you do a windowing where you group all the elements into one list and write to that.

Of course, there is the hacky way to do it without windowing, which I will explain if this use case does not seem to work out with you (or if you are curious)

Let me know if I missed anything! :)

Comment: so                                               .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)) creates a trigger for each element in the window?

Comment: @Nutel the `.withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))` creates a trigger which forces the window to close as soon as you have one element. Thus you have a window with one element in it. However, if you want, you can choose it to fire every 10 elements instead (you would do this in the situation where your instance has a lot of free memory and CPU to utilize. Example, only 30% CPU or Memory is used for a single element firing, maybe you can increase the elements to maybe 10 and then fire the window and that way within that frame your usage is 80 % and you maximized your hardware)

Comment: @Nutel I take it that you don't need the hacky solution then? And hope it helped! Let me know if you have other questions :)

Comment: If I fire after 10 elements, won't Beam create a window with 10 elements and all subsequent operations will be executed on these 10 elements, i.e. TopElement will choose a top element from concatenation of all results of ExtractElements so there will be one output not 10? out of curiosity what's the idea behind the hacky solution?

Comment: @Nutel that is a good question. But such an event would not occur in your use case since you would be writing your own `DoFn` function (which was in the above example) which would run the heuristics of top for each message. So to give you an idea `ExtractElements()` may take as input an `Element` and parse the Element for `Sub-Elements`, compute the top and output `TopSubElement` which you would write to file. In this case you would not need to write a `TopElement()` function and now I see why my answer could be a bit confusing.

Comment: The hacky solution would be to write your own `DoFn` function where you would write to a file system (maybe google cloud storage using the API, or maybe even local file system). So you would have something like `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("gs://demo-bucket")` at the beginning of the function and then after processing, write to file. At the end of the Class function then perform `fw.close()` and now you do not really require windowing and you would be writing to file everytime you write. ***NOTE*** you would need to manage unique filenames (and maybe even synchronization).

Comment: ^^ The commands above were sudo code. But hopefully that'll make sense

Comment: Step 2 is the most heavy operation in my case, which means I'll need to parallelize it, so I can't merge Step 1 and Step 2 in one DoFn. Or did I misunderstand your option?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. If that is the case, what you can do is take `ExtractElements()` which would take as input an `Element` and output a single `List<SubElements>`. Then your `TopElement()` would take as input the `List<SubElements>` and return the top `SubElement` from the single element which would be written to file. Does that make sense?

Comment: Of course you could have a middle function between the two that I suggested that could potentially do some data cleaning or mapping or data enrichment etc.

Comment: I am still confused on how to parallelize converstion from List<SubElements> to List<SubElements'> (Step 2). If I explode the List into separate elements to do Step2, it will be "merged" with elements from other Lists. If I keep the List as it is, I'll need to do everything in one DoFn.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me a small sample of actual data (even just a single msg would do, or even a fake msg) so that I could give a small demo from that? Because, you are right in a sense, but it would be easier to explain with an actual example. And I can just edit my post with that example. Is that doable?

Comment: This does not work: elements that arrive during each second can be added to the same group.